# Read from Zip files in Helm Templates

Tags: zip, kubernetes-helm

I have the following Template

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: poc-secrets-secret-data-txt-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
type: Opaque
stringData:
  myZipdata: {{ .Files.Get "secrets/base64.zip" }}
```

I get the following error when i do install helm

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: control characters are not allowed
```

My use case is to send zip file only. Can anyone suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YAML structure can only hold textual data.  Similarly, within a Secret, `stringData` specifically holds textual data.  Neither channel can communicate a (binary) zip file.

However: if you use `data` instead of `stringData`, that's allowed to contain binary data, and the Helm `b64enc` function can base64 encode arbitrary binary data into a valid YAML string.  There's [an example](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#encoding) in the Helm documentation "Accessing Files Inside Templates" page.  For your example, you can:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: poc-secrets-secret-data-txt-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
type: Opaque
data: # not stringData
  myZipdata: {{ .Files.Get "secrets/base64.zip" | b64enc }} # add base64 encode
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can't do it via helm from what I found.

My solution was

```
kubectl create configmap my-scripts  --from-file=my-scripts.jar

kubectl describe configmap my-scripts
...
Data
====
Events:  <none>
```

Which looks empty, but when you do the volume mount with helm to this configmap it will work.